# How to read the azure blob content using azure api management

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-api-management

I have a azure blob storage where i have placed a json file with some sample data, using postman i able to read the data present in the json file like below
[postman screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3N3s.png)

I would like to get the same response using azure apim, for that i have created a an azure apim resource and in the api's i have added one API and a GET operation to see this json file content as response but is saying "blob not found or some time resource not found" when tested through apim as below

[Apim screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L20hB.png)

and using this url https://filetransfer.azure-api.net/filenet

Doing i need to pass any thing here to read that json file content ? I am new to APIM so i am not understanding how to achieve this

With in APIM i tried passing the filename in the query string of the gateway url like this
https://filetransfer.azure-api.net/filenet?filename=testfile

but could not be able to get any response and still i got the same error as

```
<Error>
    <Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
    <Message>The specified blob does not exist.
RequestId:df7adae7-d01e-0067-0604-19cd2c000000
Time:2022-12-26T08:32:28.3446481Z</Message>
</Error>
```

or

```
<Error>
    <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
    <Message>The specified resource does not exist.
RequestId:df7adae7-d01e-0067-0604-19cd2c000000
Time:2022-12-26T08:32:28.3446481Z</Message>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce your scenario in my environment and got the below results:-**

I deployed one **`APIM resource`** in my Azure Portal > Created one API based on **`Azure Storage`** and used Get-Blob by adding it as an operation> I also enabled managed Identity on Azure APIM resource and added that identity **`Storage Blob Data Owner role`** at my Storage account container level.

[image]

I configured **`GET URL to /`** and not the URL of the APIM and was able to successfully get the Blob content via APIM.

[image]

[image]

Verify your Container name and Blob Name correctly form your storage account to avoid Container or Blob not found error.

I sent the test and retrieved blob contents successfully: -

[image]

**Blob Content :-**

[image]

I got the same error as yours, If I do not use / in Get Blob but if i used /< container-name >

[image]

Now, If I run the test, I get same error as yours:-

The Request URL changes in the Test when I add container name beside Get Blob URL - /

[image]

[image]

You need to use / in Get Blob operation URL instead of /filenet and verify your Container and Blob name in the Header while testing the API.

**Reference:**
[Secure Azure Blob Storage with Azure API Management & Managed Identities | by Marcus Tee | Marcus Tee Anytime | Medium](https://medium.com/marcus-tee-anytime/secure-azure-blob-storage-with-azure-api-management-managed-identities-b0b82b53533c) by Marcus Tee.

Comment: Thanks Venkatesan, I will try this way and check it