# How to secure the Folder with sudirectories and files stored in the Blob storage account with API Management?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I had stored a folder with Javascript files, and given Anonymous Public Access to the Blob Storage container.

Now due to company policy, I cannot allow Anonymous access.

I have currently created a SAS token URL for the whole folder.

And created an API Management with HTTP URL, and set the SAS token URL in that.

But I need the ability to access the files in this folder using the API Management URL.

But I am not able to do that. Is it possible to access files using the folder's SAS URL protected by APIM ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to secure your folder in Azure storage account and access the Javascript files inside it without SAS token. Refer the steps below:-

1. Make sure you enable Managed identity in your APIM instance and assign it **`Storage Blob Data Owner`** role:-

[image]

[image]

2. Created on Azure Storage API in APIM instance with the settings and click on Subscription required like below:-

[image]

3. Create one operation named Get Blob and in URL add **`/`** with Get method:-

[image]

4. In the Design add below Inbound processing Policy, replace the storage account name with yours:-

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <set-variable name="ContainerName" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Container"))" />
        <set-variable name="BlobName" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Blob"))" />
        <base />
        <set-header name="Blob" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="Container" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="Sec-Fetch-Site" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="Sec-Fetch-Mode" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="Sec-Fetch-Dest" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="Accept" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="Accept-Encoding" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="Referer" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="X-Forwarded-For" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="x-ms-version" exists-action="override">
            <value>@{string version = "2017-11-09"; return version;}</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-backend-service base-url="@{
string containerName = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("ContainerName");
string blobName = context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("BlobName");
return String.Format("https://siliconstrg543.blob.core.windows.net/{0}/{1}", containerName, blobName);
}" />
        <authentication-managed-identity resource="https://storage.azure.com/" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

[image]

5. Now, Test your Container and blob with by giving its name and the blob content will be reflected in the request like below:-

[image]

[image]

**References:-**

[Secure Azure Blob Storage with Azure API Management & Managed Identities | by Marcus Tee | Marcus Tee Anytime | Medium](https://medium.com/marcus-tee-anytime/secure-azure-blob-storage-with-azure-api-management-managed-identities-b0b82b53533c)

[How to read the azure blob content using azure api management - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74918970/how-to-read-the-azure-blob-content-using-azure-api-management/74927862#74927862) By Venkatesan